# can not read value of coordinates from another class

Tags: java, panel, coordinate

My code is written in java. I have 2 classes, first draws 3 rectangles which are move while program is running, second has one panel which can do drag & drop, now I want to create a method which checks if rectangles and drag & drop panel intersects or not, but I cant call coordinates from one class to another class. How can I check if they intersects or not???

Answer (score 0):

What lib do you use? Swing, Java2d, awt, swt, javaFx? For different library - different solutions :)
 But mostly, classes like Rectangle have such methods like `intersects(Shape shape)`